# First order differential equation with given particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the standard method for finding solutions of differential equations such as this one? (if there is any) $$xy'=y^2-(2x+1)y+x^2+2x$$

where $y=ax+b$ is a particular solution.

Do I substitute $y$ with $ax+b+u(x)$ and then search for a solution or am I not noticing something and there's quicker way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your hint is "there exists $a,b$ such thaht $y(x)=ax+b$ is solution". We find easily that $y(x)=x$ and $y(x)=x+1$ are solutions.

Hint: Note that your equation is
$$xy^{\prime}(x)-x=(y(x)-x)(y(x)-x-1)$$
Now put $y(x)=x+z(x)$.

Comment: It's that simple? Cool, I'd never thought it would be so... not complicated. Thanks.